# SQL if statement doesn't work when checking for an existing row in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a trigger that checks if another column already has the same value. This however returns a print even if there is no other row with the same value. I believe the mistake is in the IF clause, but I can't figure it out. For the database the following SQL is used.

```sql
CREATE TABLE  Gebruiker
(
    gebruikersnaam VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    voornaam VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    achternaam VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    adresregel_1 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    adresregel_2 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    postcode CHAR(7) NULL,
    plaatsnaam VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    land VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    geboortedag CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    mailbox VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    wachtwoord VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    verkoper BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_gebruiker 
        PRIMARY KEY (gebruikersnaam),
)

CREATE TABLE Verkoper 
(
    gebruikersnaam VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    banknaam VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    rekeningnummer VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    controleoptienaam CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    creditcardnummer INTEGER NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_Verkoper 
        PRIMARY KEY (gebruikersnaam),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Verkoper_Gebruikersnaam 
        FOREIGN KEY (gebruikersnaam) REFERENCES Gebruiker(gebruikersnaam),
    CONSTRAINT ck_rekening 
        CHECK (rekeningnummer is NOT NULL OR creditcardnummer is NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT ck_controleoptie 
        CHECK (controleoptienaam IN('Post', 'Creditcard'))
)

CREATE TABLE Voorwerp
(
    voorwerpnummer NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
    titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    beschrijving VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    startprijs NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL,
    betalingswijze VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    betalingsinstructie VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    plaatsnaam VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    land VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    looptijd INTEGER NOT NULL,
    looptijdbegindag CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    looptijdbegintijdstip CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    verzendkosten NUMERIC(5,2),
    verzendinstructie VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    verkoper VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    koper VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    looptijdeindedag CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    looptijdeindetijdstip CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    veilingGesloten BIT NOT NULL,
    verkoopprijs NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_voorwerp 
        PRIMARY KEY (voorwerpnummer),
    CONSTRAINT fk_voorwerp_verkoper 
        FOREIGN KEY (verkoper) REFERENCES verkoper(gebruikersnaam),
    CONSTRAINT fk_voorwerp_gebruiker 
        FOREIGN KEY (koper) REFERENCES gebruiker(gebruikersnaam)
)

CREATE TABLE Bod 
(
    voorwerpnummer NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
    euro NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL,
    gebruikersnaam CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    datum CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    tijdaanduiding CHAR(8) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_Bod 
        PRIMARY KEY (voorwerpnummer, euro),
    CONSTRAINT ak_Bod_Gebruiker_BodDag_Tijdstip 
        UNIQUE (gebruikersnaam, datum, tijdaanduiding),
    CONSTRAINT ak_Bod_Voorwerp_BodDag_Tijdstip 
        UNIQUE (voorwerpnummer, datum, tijdaanduiding),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Bod_Voorwerp 
        FOREIGN KEY (voorwerpnummer) REFERENCES Voorwerp(voorwerpnummer)
)

INSERT INTO Gebruiker
VALUES ('Lars', 'Lars', 'Last_name', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '04/04/2019', 'lars@mymailbox.cloud', 'MyPassword', 1)

INSERT INTO Verkoper
VALUES ('Lars', 'ING', 'NL42INGB0685', 'Creditcard', 654654665);

INSERT INTO Voorwerp (voorwerpnummer, titel, beschrijving, startprijs, betalingswijze, betalingsinstructie, plaatsnaam, land, looptijd, looptijdbegindag, looptijdbegintijdstip, verzendkosten, verzendinstructie, verkoper, looptijdeindedag, looptijdeindetijdstip, veilinggesloten)
VALUES (3434343434, 'test', 'test', 10.00, 'bank/giro', 'betaald voor levering', 'Arnhem', 'Nederland', 7, '20/04/2019', '13:30:15', 5.00, 'pakket post', 'Lars', '27/04/2019', '12:30:15', 0);
```

The trigger in question:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER hoger_bod 
ON Bod
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted AS i
               WHERE i.voorwerpnummer IN (SELECT voorwerpnummer FROM Bod))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'This voorwerpnummer already has a row.';
    END;
END;
```

This trigger should return 'This voorwerpnummer already has a row.' when the `Bod` column has a row with the same `voorwerpnummer` value.

To test this I've used the following INSERT statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Bod VALUES (3434343434, 5.01, 'Lars', '12/12/2011', '11:11:16')
```

This returns 'This voorwerpnummer already has a row.', even though there are no rows.

For a second insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO Bod VALUES (3434343434, 10.00, 'Lars', '12/12/2011', '11:16:16')
```

If you'd like to test this; here is a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?fiddle=1777fa6548beef3ac5e701b7bc2c489c

Comment: If `voorwerpnummer` needs to be unique, why not use a `UNIQUE INDEX`?

Comment: It doesn't need to be unique, I just need to know so I can check for the previous rows and see if the increment in the 'euro' column

Comment: Your trigger is an **`AFTER`** `INSERT` trigger; so the row will *always* exist in the table. The row has already been inserted. The check wouild be like "Put a blue ball in the bag. Now check if there is a blue ball in the bag. If there is, let me know." There will *always* be a blue ball in the bag. This seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: This is a common error: a `FOR` trigger runs *after* the insert has already happened, but before it is committed, and gives you a chance to roll things back if they are not to your liking. The trigger will *always* find a matching row because we just inserted it. Either find a way to distinguish old rows from new, or use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger (but those have maintenance issues with changing table structures), or best of all, find a way to do it with a constraint, computed column, indexed view, or anything else other than a trigger.

Comment: You *could* do this with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, however, if you simply want to check if a row already exists, and `PRINT` a line to the output window, a trigger doesn't seem to be the right choice.

Comment: Why not count the numbers of rows in Bod with the same voorwerpnummer, and only print when the number > 1 in your trigger

Comment: After the IF clause there will be more checks for certain intervals in 'euro'. So a trigger is needed in my opinion. I will try @GuidoG, seems like a solid idea.

Comment: Another option is to exclude the current inserted `ID` from table `Bod` in your query, so that is cannot find the row that was inserted

Answer (score 1):

As per @GuidoG, try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hoger_bod ON Bod
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF  (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM inserted AS i
               WHERE i.voorwerpnummer IN (SELECT voorwerpnummer FROM Bod)) >1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'This voorwerpnummer already has a row.';
    END;
END;
```